# Disqus resetting comment count to 0

Tags: comments, disqus

For some reason my Disqus comment system seems to resetting the comment counts to 0 on the main page. If you load [my site](https://scotthelme.co.uk/) the current blog at the top has 1 comment, you can see it says 1 very briefly then changes to 0. Refresh the page and keep an eye out for it if you miss it. I have no idea why it's doing this. If you click the blog to read it, the comment count correctly displays 1.

Also, the 3rd blog down regarding VPNs, reads 0 comments on the main page and 0 comments when you click on it, even though it has a comment.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

*Edit*

Plugin [link](http://wordpress.org/plugins/disqus-comment-system/).

Comment: Please provide details on how exactly are you implementing Disqus at your site.

Comment: Installed and configured the Disqus plugin as per the instructions.

Comment: Please _link_ to plugin when it's relevant to question. I know it _seems_ tad obvious, but not everyone knows every plugin out there. Link to it is extremely helpful for people to go take a look right away, rather than spend time figuring out which plugin you meant and where is it.

Comment: Sure thing, link added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further investigation I found that removing and re-installing the plugin has no negative effect on existing comments and resolved the issue.